# Scipy minimization for a caffe neural network gives the same initial condition as the result

Tags: python, scipy, caffe, minimize

I'm applying a set of thresholds to the weights of a caffe neural network and get the accuracy.But this accuracy is less than the conventional model without the threshold.

What I tried was define a function that takes in the threshold as a parameter and in there apply it to the neural network and return the reciprocal of the accuracy.

Then I used scipt.optimization.minimize with the method 'SLSQP' to tune this threshold such that it gives the maximum accuracy.

```
import numpy as np
import caffe
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from kernel_apprx import *
import time



def objective(ths):
    #return ths[0]**2+ths[1]**2
    net=caffe.Net('cifar10_quick_customised_opt.prototxt','cifar10_quick_iter_4000.caffemodel',caffe.TEST)
    k_aprox(net,"conv1","conv1_cus",ths[0],ths[1])
    net.forward()
    acc=net.blobs["accuracy"].data*100
    print "################## report #################\n\tthresholds: %s\n\taccuracy: %.16f%%"%(ths,acc)
    return 1/float(acc)





con={'type':'ineq','fun':con1}
constr=[con]


th0=[0.01,0.98]
b1=(0.0001,1.0)


bnds=(b1,b1)
tic=time.time()
sol=minimize(objective,th0,method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds,options={'disp': True ,'eps' : 1e-4,'ftol': 1e-10})
```

Here 'objective' is the function containing the neural network. 
But when I run it, it runs for about 3 iterations and gives the same initial condition as the result no matter what I put in the initial condition saying 'Optimization terminated successfully.'.In the above example it returns [0.2,0.98]

please help.

thank you.

Comment: Without knowing the entire code (e.g. your `objective`) it is hard to help. Could you provide all code that is needed to reproduce your finding?!

Comment: I have updated the post with the whole code.